# char* buffer = new vs char buffer[] in C++

Tags: c++

```
1. char* buffer = new char[size]
2. char buffer[size]
```

I'm new to C++ and I see most places creating buffers using the first example. I know in the first method, the data in that part of memory can be passed on until manually deleted using `delete[]`. While using the second method, the buffer would have a lifetime depending on the scope. If I only plan on the buffer lasting through a particular function and I don't plan on passing it to anything else, does it matter which method I use?

Comment: The biggest differentiation is to consider what happens when exceptions are thrown.

Comment: A safe way to handle exceptions with first example would be usage of smart pointers...

Comment: Does size compile time value? if not only 1; or equivalent is possible.

Comment: If `size` is a variable (e.g. it doesn't evaluate to a compile time constant) then the second form is a variable-length array - which is not standard C++   (it is a non-standard extension supported by some, but not all, C++ compilers).

Answer (score 4):

```
char* buffer = new char[size]
```

This is portable, but should be avoided. Until you *really* know what you're doing, using `new` directly is almost always a mistake (and when you do know what you're doing, it's still a mistake, but you'll know that without being told).

```
char buffer[size]
```

This depends on how you've defined `size`. If it's a constant (and fairly small), then this is all right. If it's not a constant, then any properly functioning compiler is required to reject it (but some common ones accept it anyway).

If it's constant, but "large", the compiler will accept the code, but it's likely to fail when you try to execute it. In this case, anything over a million is normally too large, and anything more than a few hundred thousand or so becomes suspect.

There is one exception to that though: if this is defined outside any function (i.e., as a global variable), then it can safely be much larger than a local variable can be. At the same time, I feel obliged to point out that I consider global variables something that should normally be avoided as a rule (and I'm far from being alone in holding that opinion).

Also note that these two are (more or less) mutually exclusive: if `size` is a constant, you generally want to avoid dynamic allocation, but it has to be a constant to just define an array (again, with a properly functioning compiler).

Unless `size` is fairly small constant, most of the time you should avoid both of these. What you most likely want is either:

```
std::string buffer;
```

or:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
```

or possibly:

```
std::array<char, size> buffer;
```

The first two of these can allocate space for the buffer dynamically, but generally keep the allocation "hidden", so you don't normally need to deal with it directly. The `std::array` is pretty much like the `char buffer[size]`, (e.g., has a fixed size, and is really on suitable for fairly small sizes) but enforces that the size has to be a const, and gives you roughly the same interface as `vector` (minus anything that would change the number of elements, since that's a constant with `std::array`).

Comment: To be noted: `std::array` comes with the same limitations for size as a raw array on stack.

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is that the first variant is dynamic allocation and the second one is not. You require dynamic allocation when you do not know at compile time, how much memory you will need. That means when "size" is not entirely a constant but somehow calculated at runtime depending on external input.

It is a good practice¹ to use containers that handle dynamic memory internally and thus ensure that you do not have to delete manually which is often a source for bugs and memory leaks.
A common, dynamic container for all kinds of data is
`std::vector<char>` (don't forget to `#include <vector>` )

However if you do handle texts, use the class `std::string` which also handles the memory internally. Raw `char*` arrays are a remainder from old C.

¹that good practice has the main exception when you don't use primitive data types but your own classes which store some massive amount of data. Reason is that `std::vector<>` performs copy operations when resized (and those are more expensive the larger the data).
However once you have come that far in your C++ projects, you should know about "smart pointers" by then which are the safe solution for those special cases.

By the way, with `&the_vector[0]` (address of the first element in the vector) you can get a pointer that behaves pretty much like the char array and thus can be used for older functions that do not accept vectors directly.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So if I see `char* buffer = new ` somewhere, it has more to do with an historical holdout than anything necessarily dealing with performance?

Comment: @Krunkenstein Pretty much. Well, under certain circumstances, the array will be faster than strings, but that's only really worth the risk when you have stuff like low-level networking or transferring data from/to GPUs. You should be aware of when it is worth the risk. Nowadays even in networking, it often won't be worth the risk anymore as so many vulnarabilities happened through raw memory accesses (like pointers) within networking code. See the heartbleed bug for example. Btw. see the little addition I made to my response above.